# Why is my Text Change Listener not working?

Tags: java, android

Why is my "addTextChangedListener" on android not working? Here is my code:

**activity_ticketing.xml**

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".TicketingMain.Ticketing">

    <!-- Main Content -->

    <!-- HEADING -->

    <com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/button_logout"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|right"
        android:layout_margin="16dp"

        android:layout_marginStart="28dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="100dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/icon_exit" />

    <com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView
        android:id="@+id/materialCardView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="75dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
        android:minHeight="200dp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
            android:id="@+id/constraintLayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView_route"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginStart="28dp"
                android:text="Tacloban - Tanawan"
                android:textSize="14sp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.285" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView_vehicle"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
                android:text="ZZZ999"
                android:textSize="14sp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/textView_route"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/textView_route"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView_route" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView_driver"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginStart="32dp"
                android:text="Driver Name"
                android:textSize="14sp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/textView_route"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/textView_route" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView_conductor"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginStart="32dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                android:text="Conductor Name"
                android:textSize="14sp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/textView_vehicle"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView_driver" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView_numberOfPassengers"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
                android:text="0"
                android:textSize="24sp"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/textView3"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView3" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView3"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
                android:text="Passengers"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

    </com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView>
    <!-- HEADING END -->

    <!-- ROUTEPOST ORIGIN -->
    <!-- ROUTEPOST ORIGIN END -->

    <!-- MAIN -->
    <com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView
        android:id="@+id/materialCardView2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/materialCardView">

        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <!-- spinner_direction -->

            <Spinner
                android:id="@+id/spinner_direction"
                android:layout_width="200dp"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
                android:textAlignment="center"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/textView"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/textView"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

            <!-- textView_currentPost -->
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView_currentPost"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
                android:background="@drawable/border_box"
                android:text="Current"
                android:textAlignment="center"
                android:textAllCaps="true"
                android:textSize="20sp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/button_prev"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/button_next"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/button_prev"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/button_prev" />

            <!-- button_next -->
            <com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
                android:id="@+id/button_next"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
                android:textAlignment="center"
                app:icon="@drawable/ic_right_arrow"
                app:iconGravity="textStart"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/textView_currentPost"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/spinner_direction" />

            <!-- button_prev -->
            <com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
                android:id="@+id/button_prev"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
                android:textAlignment="center"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                app:icon="@drawable/ic_left"
                app:iconGravity="textStart"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/textView_currentPost"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/spinner_direction" />

            <!-- button_postCurrentRoutePost -->

            <!-- button_logout -->

            <!-- textView = "Direction" -->
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
                android:text="Direction"
                android:textSize="24sp"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

            <!-- textView_currentLocation -->
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView_currentLocation"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
                android:text="No current location set"
                android:textSize="24sp"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/button_next"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/button_prev"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView_currentPost" />

            <!-- button_nextDestination -->
            <com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
                android:id="@+id/button_nextDestination"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                android:textAlignment="center"
                app:icon="@drawable/ic_right_arrow"
                app:iconGravity="textStart"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/textView_currentLocation"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/textView_currentPost"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView_currentLocation" />

            <!-- button_prevDestination -->
            <com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
                android:id="@+id/button_prevDestination"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:textAlignment="center"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                app:icon="@drawable/ic_left"
                app:iconGravity="textStart"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/textView_currentPost"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView_currentLocation" />

            <!-- textView_currentPostDestination -->
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView_currentPostDestination"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
                android:background="@drawable/border_box"
                android:text="Current"
                android:textAlignment="center"
                android:textAllCaps="true"
                android:textSize="20sp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:onClick="onClick"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/button_prevDestination"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/button_nextDestination"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/button_prevDestination"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/button_nextDestination" />

            <com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
                android:id="@+id/button_postDestination"
                style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.Button"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="65dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                android:text="Submit Destination"
                android:textAlignment="center"
                app:iconGravity="textStart"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/button_nextDestination"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/textView_currentPostDestination"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView_currentPostDestination" />

            <!-- RECEIPT -->
            <com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView
                android:id="@+id/materialCardView3"
                android:layout_width="347dp"
                android:layout_height="332dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="1.0"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/button_postDestination">

                <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent">

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/textView4"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginStart="24dp"
                        android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
                        android:text="Destination"
                        android:textSize="18sp"
                        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/textView_receiptDestination"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
                        android:text="Tacloban - Tanawan"
                        android:textSize="18sp"
                        android:textStyle="bold"
                        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/textView4"
                        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/textView4" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/textView6"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
                        android:text="Passengers"
                        android:textSize="18sp"
                        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/textView4"
                        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView4" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/textView_receiptPassengers"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
                        android:text="0"
                        android:textSize="18sp"
                        android:textStyle="bold"
                        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/textView6"
                        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/textView6" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/textView8"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
                        android:text="Fare"
                        android:textSize="18sp"
                        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/textView6"
                        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView6" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/textView_receiptFare"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="0.00"
                        android:textSize="18sp"
                        android:textStyle="bold"
                        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/textView_receiptPassengers"
                        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/textView8" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/textView10"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
                        android:text="Total Due"
                        android:textSize="18sp"
                        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/textView8"
                        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView8" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/textView_receiptTotal"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="0.00"
                        android:textSize="18sp"
                        android:textStyle="bold"
                        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/textView_receiptFare"
                        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/textView10" />

                    <com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView
                        android:id="@+id/materialCardView4"
                        android:layout_width="108dp"
                        android:layout_height="97dp"
                        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
                        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/textView_receiptTotal"
                        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView_receiptDestination">

                        <ImageView
                            android:id="@+id/imageView_qrCode"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="match_parent"
                            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

                    </com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView>

                    <RadioGroup
                        android:id="@+id/radioGroup_discount"
                        android:layout_width="205dp"
                        android:layout_height="106dp"
                        android:layout_marginEnd="140dp"
                        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView10"
                        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.615">

                        <RadioButton
                            android:id="@+id/radioButton_noDiscount"
                            android:layout_width="128dp"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_marginStart="60dp"
                            android:checked="true"
                            android:text="No Discount"
                            android:textSize="12sp"
                            android:textStyle="bold"
                            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView10" />

                        <RadioButton
                            android:id="@+id/radioButton_ssDiscount"
                            android:layout_width="125dp"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_marginStart="60dp"
                            android:text="Senior/Student"
                            android:textSize="12sp"
                            android:textStyle="bold"
                            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView10" />

                        <RadioButton
                            android:id="@+id/radioButton_spDiscount"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_marginStart="60dp"
                            android:text="Special Discount"
                            android:textSize="12sp"
                            android:textStyle="bold" />


                    </RadioGroup>

                    <Button
                        android:id="@+id/button_accept"
                        android:layout_width="108dp"
                        android:layout_height="74dp"
                        android:text="Accept"
                        app:backgroundTint="#009688"
                        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/materialCardView4"
                        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/materialCardView4"
                        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/materialCardView4" />


                </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
            </com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView>

<!--            <SearchView-->
<!--                android:layout_width="0dp"-->
<!--                android:layout_height="0dp"-->
<!--                android:id="@+id/search"-->
<!--                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/button_postDestination"-->
<!--                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/button_prevDestination"-->
<!--                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/button_prevDestination"-->
<!--                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/button_postDestination" />-->

                        <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                android:id="@+id/editText"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/button_postDestination"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/button_prevDestination"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/button_prevDestination"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/button_prevDestination">

                <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
                    android:id="@+id/textKm"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:hint="Km" />
            </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>


        </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
    </com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView>
    <!-- MAIN END -->
    <!-- MAIN -->
    <!-- HEADING -->

    <!-- LOGOUT -->
    <!-- LOGOUT END -->

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

**Ticketing.java**

```
EditText editText;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_ticketing);
    editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.textKm);
    editText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
            Log.e("TEXT", "A");
        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
            Log.e("TEXT", "A");
        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            Log.e("TEXT", "A");
        }
    });
}
```

I don't get any error. On debugging, it doesn't stop on any of the overrides.

Comment: Explain more what is not working getting any error?

Comment: Please see my edits. Thank you.

Comment: Did you set layout `activity_ticketing` to activity using `setContentView` before using `editText`?

Comment: Did you forgot to `setContentView()`? Looks from code it's not there so..

Comment: Yes Id did I just didn't include it in the codes here for brevity. Please see my edit.

Comment: Post the full `activity_ticketing.xml` i think there are some layout issues. You might be triggering wrong input fields ! @Ibanez1408

Comment: Hey, your code is perfect. I was suspecting for typecasting but it is not. No customization added in between. For me, your code is working fine. So check again your logs, or do the proper analysis. Deleting my answer as it is not answering your question

Comment: @SantanuSur, the whole xml is included now  Sir. please see my edit.

Comment: What you mean by Not working? Are you writing on EditText but no log print?

Comment: @Ibanez1408 I tried your code from xml and just onCreate() it is work perfectly. I hope you are not clearing or removing TextWatcher anywhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set in tow way

**First Way:**

```
 EditText et_auto_complete_edit_text;
 et_auto_complete_edit_text = findViewById(R.id.et_auto_complete_edit_text);
 et_auto_complete_edit_text.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
               s.toString()
            }
        });
```

**XML:**

```
 <EditText
            android:id="@+id/et_auto_complete_edit_text"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_weight="8"
            android:background="@color/gray_light_EA"
            android:drawableRight="@mipmap/ic_search_new"
            android:drawablePadding="@dimen/margin5dp"
            android:hint="Search here"
            android:inputType="text"
            android:maxLines="1"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:textColor="@color/black"
            android:textColorHint="@color/grey"
            android:visibility="visible" />
```

**Second Way :**

```
      SearchView search;
      search = findViewById(R.id.search);
      search.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
                fetchData(query);
                return false;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
                //collectionProductsListAdapter.getFilter().filter(newText);
                return false;
            }
        });
        search.setOnSearchClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
            }
        });
        search.setOnCloseListener(new SearchView.OnCloseListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onClose() {
                return false;
            }
        });
```

**XML:**

```
<androidx.appcompat.widget.SearchView
                    xmlns:n2="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
                    android:id="@+id/search"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    n2:searchIcon="@mipmap/ic_et_search" />
```

Hope this may help you first way is more easy.

Comment: I used the second way but I still couldn't even break at the methods. Could it be a layout issue?

Comment: In second way method called when clicked on search icon from keyboard becase code wrote into "onQueryTextSubmit" method.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing it to EditText

```
<android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
            android:id="@+id/editText"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            android:ems="10"
            android:hint="Km"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/button_prevDestination"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/button_prevDestination"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView_currentPostDestination">

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/textKm"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
```

Working fine in my code.